# Maximum size of .text section?

Tags: elf

When the ELF file loading process, `.text` section is mapped to a memory segment. I would like to know:

1. What is the maximum value of a segment size ?
2. What is the maximum value of `.text` section size ?

Answer (score 4):

Elf32 or Elf64?

According to [ELF specification](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f00/docs/elf.pdf), for Elf32 the section size is stored in 32 bits (`Elf32_Word`). So, the maximum size would be 4294967295 bytes (4 GiB).

Comment: I assume you meant 4294967295 bytes

Comment: @Hackndo maybe it's stored in a signed integer (which would make no sense, but it's still possible)

Comment: Then it would be 2 GB, not 4 GB. I'm just noticing that `2147483647 bytes (4 Gb)` is incoherent

Comment: You're right, but I didn't write "2147483647 bytes (4 Gb)", I only wrote 4GB, my post was edited. Why are the posts edited so roughly?
The definition I found for Elf32_Word is "unsigned long int", so I would vote for 4294967295 bytes - 4GB.